# Custom Fields and Reports

Tags: reporting, formula-field

On the Opportunity we have a custom field called 'Contract Term' it is a picklist with values 12 Months, 24, Months, 36 Months and 60 Months.

So Customer installation Complete Date is the start date of the contract and the contract term justifies the length.

We would like to run reports on all opportunities that have contracts expiring within 3 months. Any ideas on how I can start this process or if there is something I can utilize that is already built.

I imagine I need a particular formula due to the picklist on the contract term and close date being a date field. I was thinking of creating a custom formula field to add close date plus the contact term length to give an output end date.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this effectively, you need to also know when the Contract Start Date is.  You could add a formula field for Contract_Expire_Date__c like so:

> Contract_Start_Date__c + (VALUE(Contract_Term__c) *30)

When you run the report, you will want to add a filter like so:

> Contract_Expire_Date__c equals NEXT 3 MONTHS

Comment: I would need to create a Contract Start Date field but this wouldnt help capture previous records.  Our start date would be the Customer Installation Completed Date field. Does this mean I need to just create a report and add the filter ?

Comment: Also, the contract term field is a picklist so I cant use it:(

Comment: I've edited my response to deal with the picklist value.  Yes, you can use your 'Customer Installation Completed Date' if that is effectively your contract start date.  You'll still need the Contract_Expire_Date__c formula field to find out when the contract ends and then use that field as a filter for your report.